# Turris/Luci: Route server on br-lan to br-wan?

Tags: linux, router, routing, firewall

The routing table on Turris Omnia looks like this:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         1xx.1xx.246.161 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br-wan
10.111.222.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-guest_turris
1xx.1xx.246.160 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 br-wan
1xx.1xx.246.161 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br-wan
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

My webserver is sitting on 1xx.1xx.246.161.

I want to access NFS from my NAS (192.168.1.10) from 1xx.1xx.246.161.

Here is a drawing of the physical cabling:

```
+------+ 
|      |------(br-lan)-----[NAS]
|      |
|Turris|------(br-wan)-----[WWW]
|      |                        
|      |------(br-wan)-----[Internet]
+------+
```

So I need to punch a hole in the firewall to allow NFS requests from br-wan to br-lan (preferably only to the host 1xx.1xx.246.161). It would also be OK if 1xx.1xx.246.161 can access everything on br-lan. If it helps, we can give WWW an additional private address space IP-address, so that network can be routed in.

I can ping 1xx.1xx.246.161 from 192.168.1.10, but I cannot ping 192.168.1.10 from 1xx.1xx.246.161, which makes sense if there is no hole in the firewall.

How do I configure Turris Omnia to do that? Preferably through Luci (the web-admin).

Comment: for instructions for your specific router, check https://portforward.com/ . they have instructions for thousands of models of routers. Also consider that you are forwarding from WAN to LAN, not the other way around (you want DNAT, not SNAT). Third, you need to use the public IP of your router when connecting from your webhost to your LAN. No router on the public internet will pass traffic for private ip ranges like 192.168.1.x. to find your public IP, type whats my IP into any major search engine.

Comment: Yes. One router will: Mine. And that the the router we are talking about. This router is directly connected to both devices (see routing table above). So we are not talking about port forwarding. The NAS is only going to be accessible from devices in my house - not from outside.

Comment: so this router is on the interior of your network, and its not actually a WAN interface; fair enough. well, it is clear that the stateful firewall on the router is blocking your pings and other connections coming inbound on the upstream interface, so the answer remains the same. check portforward. they cover quite a range of routers.